# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Inaccurate Pushpin Location

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I am following the tutorial available [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-pushpin-markup-svg), in order to add Pushpins to a clicked location on the Forge viewer. My issue is that the pushpin is drawn on a different location to where I clicked on the viewer. I am using the exact same code that as available in the tutorial, although I have implemented it as a separate extension. 
Following is a screenshot of where the Pushpin was drawn, and where the mouse pointer was at the time it was clicked.

[image]
I have been trying to play around with the code by even manually changing the location to get the correct position, but wasn't really successful. Any help on this regard would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: the location follows the data from hitTest. If it is wrong, then the location will be wrong. I have not a quick answer for such behavior. It might be an issue with specific model. Could you email us with a small demo model? forge.help@autodesk.com .

Comment: as replied in email, I seemed not to be able to reproduce the problem.This is a test video:
https://myshare.autodesk.com/:v:/g/personal/xiaodong_liang_autodesk_com/EbZhUq3ol9FGveNz-fC3FjYBSJ3zTaj__nYMrgL_l2ErBA?e=GpASfU

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem when my app was doing components size changes with css, and I solve this calling the method **resize** of the viewer, after the visual size changes, and before the pushpin creation, like above:

```
viewer.resize()
```

Link: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#resize

I hope this can help you!